# Exception: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, casting

```
public class UserLoginInfo
{
    public UserRole Role;
    public string Username;

    public static UserLoginInfo FetchUser(string username, string password)
    {
        using (var connection = Utils.Database.GetConnection())
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Username], [Password], [Role] FROM [Users] WHERE [Username] = @username", connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader == null || !reader.Read() || !Utils.Hash.CheckPassword(username, password, (byte[])reader["Password"]))
                    throw new Exception("Wrong username or password.");

                return new UserLoginInfo { Username = (string)reader["Username"], Role = (UserRole)reader["Role"] };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I put a breakpoint and debug the error comes from this line

```
return 
    new UserLoginInfo 
    { 
        Username = (string)reader["Username"], 
        Role = (UserRole)reader["Role"] 
    };
```

I don't understand why I get this error. Please help me!

EDIT: How can I convert (string)reader["Role"] to UserRole??

```
public enum UserRole
{
    Admin,
    Maintance,
    User
}
```

Comment: You did a cast for UserRole. Do you need to do one for Username too?

Comment: See my updated answer for how to convert to your enum value.

Comment: By the way, why are your `Role` and `Username` members public?  You should at least turn them into autoprops with `public UserRole Role { get; set; }` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Role = (UserRole)reader["Role"]
```

Presumably `UserRole` is a type you have defined, hence the `SqlDataReader` does not know how to convert the data it gets from the database to this type. What is the type of this column in your database?

EDIT: As for your updated question you can do:

```
var role = (string)reader["Role"];
UserRole role = (UserRole)Enum.Parse( typeof(UserRole), role );
```

You might want to add in some extra error checking, eg checking that `role` is not null. Also, before parsing the enum you could check if the parse is valid using [Enum.IsDefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

`(UserRole)reader["Role"]` should be `(string)reader["Role"]`. There's no `UserRole` type in SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

The code is probably failing at:

```
Role = (UserRole)reader["Role"];
```

because you're trying to cast an `object` to a `UserRole` and the cast doesn't exist.

<strike>It looks like you're trying to cast `reader["Role"]` to a `UserRole` Object and I'm guessing that's what is failing.</strike>

You either need to specify (or implement) a valid cast, or implement something like `UserRole.Parse(string value)` to parse the string to a valid `UserRole` object.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're storing in the database is a `string`, but you want to convert it to an `enum` type, then you should use the [`Enum.Parse()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328348%28VS.71%29.aspx).

For example:

```
UserRole userRole = (UserRole) Enum.Parse(typeof(UserRole), (string) reader["Role"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

That means you either cannot cast `(string)reader["Username"]` (not likely), or `(UserRole)reader["Role"]` (more likely). What is `UserRole` - can you create it by casting from a db result? Don't you need something like `new UserRole(reader["Role"])`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably `(UserRole)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserRole), (string) reader["Role"])` is the most appreciated answer, and furthermore, much to my surprise, it works!! (Surprising it is that the Enum.Parse method correctly converts even the string representation of the integers to its corresponding enum values, considering enum values in database is stored as integers). But this is what I often do, to be to the point:

```
UserRole role = (UserRole)Convert.ToInt32(reader["Role"]);
```

This should be more efficient, though no way noticeable in real life.